# What is the difference between a PHP console script and web script?

Tags: php, console

I have tried reading and have understood PHP console to be a command-line interface (CLI) like one used in [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).  I do not understand the difference between a web script and a console script.  I do not see the use of having the two.

I want to crawl data from a certain link. Should I use a console script or web script and why?

Please explain in the simplest manner possible.

Answer (score 0):

One difference between a web page and a CLI instance is the way the script is executed: webpages will be loaded via a web container, while CLI's will be usually executed by the shell used to launch the PHP. Due to this, a CLI might not have access to all $_SERVER variables as the webpage as practically there is no HTTP request involved.

CLI scripts are useful for doing background tasks that are not initiated by the web server, for example a cron job that periodically cleans your database, on one that executes queued jobs. Think of CLI as shell scripts, you can write a PHP script instead of a bash one.

The PHP interpreter is the same in both cases, and it's up to you to decide which one suits best your needs: webpages are more common, however if you need to have you server do some work without waiting for a web request, the you can go with CLI.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two. In most instances, the same PHP script will run whether you execute it from the command line or via the web.

There is, however, a difference between the environment the script will execute within. A CLI script is initiated from and executed within your shell on your computer. It is very self-contained. A web script, on the other hand, is (typically) initiated via a HTTP request from a browser, passes over the web to a web server, is executed on that remote server and a result (typically a web page) is passed back to your browser. In the latter case, there are special environment variables related to the web request made available to the script.

It's a bit hard to know which is the best case for your web crawler script without knowing more detail. But I'd say a command line script is what you're after.

Answer (score -1):

Well,  basically a console script is the way for your task.

The difference resides in the fact a Webscript will block your browser, will not show your progress real-time, etc.

I was able to crawl and download about 6000 images from my beloved anime with a console script, showing the progress status, something harder with a Web script as the browser will cache the output. Also you can chain your script and also make some  cron magic(assuming you are on nix box)

Comment: Voted down with no explanation, kind of "wisdom" of an elder developer might be?